# how to use match case in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i have a VBA code to find a specific number from a set of column and rows
and return some values...(the address of the cell which have the same value that i m searching for, and it's datetime from the first column) the problem is that i must enter the exact value in the search box and if i miss a digit i will have no results....but i have a data and numbers in the sheet that have 14 digit, can we use the match case in VBA so we can find all numbers that have the same case with the value searched for?

```
Sub findReport()
Dim srch As Double
Dim cl, Rng As Range
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim u As Long
srch = InputBox("What number are you looking for?", "Search Term")
u = 1
Set ws1 = Sheet1
Set ws2 = Sheet2
Set Rng = ws1.Range("F12:O19")
For Each cl In Rng
        If cl.Value = srch Then
        ws2.Cells(u, 2).Value = cl.Address
        ws2.Cells(u, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(cl.Row, 5).Value

        u = u + 1
    End If
Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Like` and wildcards to test for a partial match:

```
If cl.Value Like "*" & srch & "*" Then
```

Comment: ++ Alternative way. [Instr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) Example `If InStr(1, cl.Value, srch) > 0 Then`

Comment: it seem that the first solution from Tim Williams give better results than the code from Siddharth Rout (which list all number from the first sheet as a find results) .although Tim Williams code will ignore some figures and dont show them in the results ....

Comment: If you're not getting the results you expect it would be useful to supply a few examples where it's not working.

Comment: Tim Williams ... am new in this site so i dont know how to post some examples ..can i post a pictures here?

Comment: You can edit your question with an example of a user input and cell values which should be matched but are not.